# Difference between "(gl -stack)" and "gl -stack"

Tags: powershell

I just wonder why I'm getting two different member lists when embedding an expression between parentheses, e.g. `gl -stack`. It seems that without the parenthesis, the expression is evaluated completely and the result passed at once to the next pipeline component. But with parenthesis, the single objects within the collection are passed one by one so that `Get-Member` is invoked for the objects in the collection instead for the collection itself.
Please see the following PowerShell interaction for an example with `Get-Location -Stack`.

Thanks in advance!

```
PS C:\temp\loc1> pushd
PS C:\temp\loc1> pushd ..\loc2
PS C:\temp\loc2> gl -stack

Path
----
C:\temp\loc1
C:\temp\loc1


PS C:\temp\loc2> gl -stack | gm


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PathInfoStack

Name          MemberType Definition
----          ---------- ----------
Clear         Method     System.Void Clear()
Contains      Method     bool Contains(System.Management.Automation.PathInfo...
CopyTo        Method     System.Void CopyTo(System.Management.Automation.Pat...
Equals        Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetEnumerator Method     System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1+Enumerator[[Syst...
GetHashCode   Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType       Method     type GetType()
Peek          Method     System.Management.Automation.PathInfo Peek()
Pop           Method     System.Management.Automation.PathInfo Pop()
Push          Method     System.Void Push(System.Management.Automation.PathI...
ToArray       Method     System.Management.Automation.PathInfo[] ToArray()
ToString      Method     string ToString()
TrimExcess    Method     System.Void TrimExcess()
Count         Property   System.Int32 Count {get;}
Name          Property   System.String Name {get;}


PS C:\temp\loc2> (gl -stack) | gm


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PathInfo

Name         MemberType Definition
----         ---------- ----------
Equals       Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode  Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType      Method     type GetType()
ToString     Method     string ToString()
Drive        Property   System.Management.Automation.PSDriveInfo Drive {get;}
Path         Property   System.String Path {get;}
Provider     Property   System.Management.Automation.ProviderInfo Provider {...
ProviderPath Property   System.String ProviderPath {get;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Get-Location -Stack` returns a `PathInfoStack` object as you have seen.  That object is derived from `Stack<T>` which implements ICollection.  When you put an expression inside `()` PowerShell evaluates that expression.  If the result is a collection then it is iterated and output.  You can see the same with this simple function:

```
PS> function GetArray() { ,@(1,2,3) }
PS> GetArray | Foreach {$_.GetType().FullName}
System.Object[]
PS> (GetArray) | Foreach {$_.GetType().FullName}
System.Int32
System.Int32
System.Int32
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any link to an 'official' help page or something similar on MSDN which explains the procedure above? I searched a lot but couldn't find any information for this.

Comment: Here's one piece of the puzzle. There's a WriteObject method that cmdlets like Get-Location use to write their output to the pipeline.  Here's a link to one of the overloads http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms568370(v=vs.85).aspx.  Note that the cmdlet can choose whether the object should be placed into the pipeline "as-is" or if PowerShell should enumerate the object (assuming it is a collection) and then place the enumerated items into the pipeline.  BTW you would see the same grouping expression behavior if you assign to a variable e.g. `$arr = GetArray; $arr | %{$_.GetType().Name}`